# Swift / how to check for existence of optional value

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having an `Array` of `NSDictionary` named `deejayTweetsDictionary`. Within the optional Key `likes` is an `Array` of `NSDictionary`.

Now I want to check if: `user == likes?.valueForKey(user) as! String`.

My Code works fine as long as `user` is within `likes`. If I login with another account - with another `user`, the app crashes on:

```
 if likes?.valueForKey(user) as! String == user {
```

How can I check my if statement if `likes` is optional and is able to contain different `user` `NSDictionaries`?

```
        let tweets = deejayTweetsDictionary[indexPath.row]

        let likes = tweets.valueForKey("likes")
        let user = backendless.userService.currentUser.objectId

        if likes != nil {

            if likes?.valueForKey(user) as! String == user {
                cell.liked = 1
            } else {
                cell.liked = 0
            }
        }
```

[image]

Again: `likes` may contain an infinity number of `[user:user]`

Question: How do I check my if statement in case `user` is not within `likes`? Help is very appreciated.

Comment: Please read the chapter *The Basics* in the Swift Language Guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crash is because of forced unwrap in the line

```
if likes?.valueForKey(user) as! String == user {
```

Try this way:

```
if let userExist = likes?.valueForKey(user) as? String where userExist == user {

       //Do your work.
}
```

You have to use this optional binding or guard keyword.

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your answer correctly. Your app crashes when unwrapping an optional value?

```
// 1. Unwrap
if let likesUser = likes?.valueForKey(user) as? String {
    if user == likesUser {
        //...
    }
}

// 2. Using guard
guard let likesUser = likes?.valueForKey(user) as? String else {
    return
}

if likesUser == user {
    //...
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your effort, but the other answer did it easily for me